# Edit post from frontend with update

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

So, I have the following code to allow front-end edit for wordpress taken from here : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9912/front-end-post-editing-using-a-form

```
 <?php
    if ( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && ! empty($_POST['post_id']) && ! empty($_POST['post_title']) && isset($_POST['update_post_nonce']) && isset($_POST['postcontent']) )
    {
    $post_id   = $_POST['post_id'];
    $post_type = get_post_type($post_id);
    $capability = ( 'page' == $post_type ) ? 'edit_page' : 'edit_post';
    if ( current_user_can($capability, $post_id) && wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['update_post_nonce'], 'update_post_'. $post_id ) )
    {
        $post = array(
        'ID'             => esc_sql($post_id),
        'post_content'   => esc_sql($_POST['postcontent']),
        'post_title'     => esc_sql($_POST['post_title'])
    );
        wp_update_post($post);

        if ( isset($_POST['edit_test']) ) update_post_meta($post_id, 'edit_test', esc_sql($_POST['edit_test']) );
        if ( isset($_POST['edit_test2']) ) update_post_meta($post_id, 'edit_test2', esc_sql($_POST['edit_test2']) );
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            wp_die("You can't do that");
                        }
                    }
                ?>

    <form class="royal_page" role="form" method="post">                 
        <input type="hidden" name="post_id" value="<?php the_ID(); ?>" />
        <?php wp_nonce_field( 'update_post_'. get_the_ID(), 'update_post_nonce' ); ?>

        <p><label for="post_title">Title</label>
        <input type="text" id="post_title" name="post_title" value="<?php echo $post->post_title; ?>" /></p>

        <p><?php wp_editor( $post->post_content, 'postcontent' ); ?></p>

        <p><label for="post_title">Test</label>
        <?php $value = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'edit_test', true); ?>
        <input type="text" id="edit_test" name="edit_test" value="<?php echo $value; ?>" /></p>

        <p><label for="post_title">Test 2</label>
        <?php $value = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'edit_test2', true); ?>
        <input type="text" id="edit_test2" name="edit_test2" value="<?php echo $value; ?>" /></p>

    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Update" />           
   </form>
```

So, editing the post itself works just fine. Once the edit is submitted and then page is refreshed.

I see the change that has been made after the refresh. However the edit form no longer contains the contents and I have to refresh the page again in order to see it (See below for image).

[image]

Does anyone know why it might be doing that and if there any solution to how to fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you need to refresh page to get updated information may be due to following reason:

Your code flow may be something like this:
1. You've posts condition at top: `<?php if(have_posts()): while(have_posts()): the_post(); ?>`

2. Then you've form processing code: `if ( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && ! empty($_POST['post_id']) && ! empty($_POST['post_title']) && isset($_POST['update_post_nonce']) && isset($_POST['postcontent']) ) ...`
3. Then you've form.

   ---

Changing the flow to this may help:
1. Put form processing code at top: `if ( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && ! empty($_POST['post_id']) && ! empty($_POST['post_title']) && isset($_POST['update_post_nonce']) && isset($_POST['postcontent']) ) ...`

2. Then put post conditions: `<?php if(have_posts()): while(have_posts()): the_post(); ?>`
3. Put form as usual.